# How to find out if an App in the Mac App Store is 64 bit

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, 64-bit

I want to buy a game in the Mac App Store.

How can I check before buying if the game/app is 64 bit or not?

I would like to know because 10.13.4 is displaying warnings about 32 bit apps/games. And probably 10.14 doesn't run 32 bit apps/games at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the app in question was updated after June 2015, or if it was released after February 2015 the app it's 64 bit.

Why:

Apple stopped accepting new apps without 64 bit support in february 2015 and stopped accepting updates to existing apps without 64 bit support in June 2015.

Comment: The game in question was last updated on 28 July 2015... so it should be 64 bit right?